# Focus on an input after creating it with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I've been doing a todo list with AngularJS and want to know if there's a way to focus on a input box after creating it by clicking on a button.

Actually, my save function inside the controller is defined like this:

```
$scope.save = function() {
    $scope.objetivo.$save()
        .then(function() {
          $scope.message = {
            text : 'Saved'
          };
          $scope.objective = new Objective();
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err.data);
          if(err.data.code === 11000) {
            text = 'This objective is already registered'
          }
          $scope.message = {
            text : text || "Error when saving"
          };
        });
    };
```

I think there's might be a way by adding the input box and then focusing on it, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Try `angular.element(document).find('<input-box-id>').focus();`

Comment: I've used your timemout function to give a time for application, while the html is created. Thank you bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0h31w10d/2/) shows you how to implement focus elements even on async logics.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <button ng-click="someAsyncFunction()">
     Set focus on async functions
   </button>
   <input type="text"
          set-focus="{{setFocus}}"> 
</div>
```

#### AngularJS Application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
   $scope.someAsyncFunction = function () 
        //the following timeout indicates ansyc functions.
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.setFocus = true;
        }, 250);
   }
});


myApp.directive('setFocus', function($timeout) {
  return {
    scope: { trigger: '@setFocus' },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.$watch('trigger', function(value) {
        if(value === "true") {
          $timeout(function() {
            element[0].focus();
          },250);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```